# How to one hot encode several categorical variables in R

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

I'm working on a prediction problem and I'm building a decision tree in R, I have several categorical variables and I'd like to one-hot encode them consistently in my training and testing set.
I managed to do it on my training data with :

```
temps <- X_train
tt <- subset(temps, select = -output)
oh <- data.frame(model.matrix(~ . -1, tt), CLASS = temps$output)
```

But I can't find a way to apply the same encoding on my testing set, how can I do that?

Comment: by encoding do you mean creating dummy variables?

Comment: Do it the same way. What is different?

Comment: Yes I mean creating dummies : for each categorical variable I need to create as many dummy as there are different categories in the variable.

Comment: @Gregor what is diffirent is that some categories might  be present in the testing set and not in the training and also the order of the dummies matters and it won't be same for the two sets

Comment: @xeco I would suggest you to look for vtreat package in R

Answer (score 48):

I recommend using the dummyVars function in the caret package:

```
library(caret)

customers <- data.frame(
  id=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
  gender=c('male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female'),
  mood=c('happy', 'sad', 'happy', 'sad','happy'),
  outcome=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
customers
id gender  mood outcome
1 10   male happy       1
2 20 female   sad       1
3 30 female happy       0
4 40   male   sad       0
5 50 female happy       0


# dummify the data
dmy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = customers)
trsf <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = customers))
trsf
id gender.female gender.male mood.happy mood.sad outcome
1 10             0           1          1        0       1
2 20             1           0          0        1       1
3 30             1           0          1        0       0
4 40             0           1          0        1       0
5 50             1           0          1        0       0
```

example [source](https://amunategui.github.io/dummyVar-Walkthrough/)

You apply the same procedure to both the training and validation sets.

Comment: I found that the caret approach (with dummyVars) is about 73% faster than the `one_hot()` function from the `mltools` package. Using the `microbenchmark` package and `iris` data set, the caret method finishes in 0.025 milliseconds, while the `one_hot()` method finishes in 0.095 milliseconds.

Comment: @DaleKube have you included the `data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = customers))` in your benchmark? Apparently `dummyVars` alone will not give you the actual dummies

Comment: If you have a dataframe with different variables, and you want to one-hot encode just some of them, you need to use something like `dummyVars(" ~ VARIABLE1 + VARIABLE2", data = customers)`

Comment: @raffamaiden yes, I included the predict() call and conversion to data.frame.

Comment: Here's an alternative using recipes (tidymodels) package: https://blog.datascienceheroes.com/how-to-use-recipes-package-for-one-hot-encoding/

Comment: An added bonus of the caret approach is that it removes any inner white space within factor levels when it makes new columns in the model matrix

Comment: dummyVars (and other libraries's functions) should drop one of the dummy variables by default to avoid collinearity: https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/dummyVars.html

Answer (score 32):

Here's a simple solution to one-hot-encode your category using no packages.

### Solution

`model.matrix(~0+category)`

It needs your categorical variable to be a factor. The factor levels must be the same in your training and test data, check with `levels(train$category)` and `levels(test$category)`. It doesn't matter if some levels don't occur in your test set.

### Example

Here's an example using the iris dataset.

```
data(iris)
#Split into train and test sets.
train <- sample(1:nrow(iris),100)
test <- -1*train

iris[test,]

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
34           5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2    setosa
106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
112          6.4         2.7          5.3         1.9 virginica
127          6.2         2.8          4.8         1.8 virginica
132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
```

`model.matrix()` creates a column for each level of the factor, even if it is not present in the data. Zero indicates it is not that level, one indicates it is. Adding the zero specifies that you do not want an intercept or reference level and is equivalent to -1.

```
oh_train <- model.matrix(~0+iris[train,'Species'])
oh_test <- model.matrix(~0+iris[test,'Species'])

#Renaming the columns to be more concise.
attr(oh_test, "dimnames")[[2]] <- levels(iris$Species)


  setosa versicolor virginica
1      1          0         0
2      0          0         1
3      0          0         1
4      0          0         1
5      0          0         1
```

P.S.
It's generally preferable to include all categories in training and test data. But that's none of my business.

Comment: This works well for one variable, but will not hit every category if  there are multiple categorical variables.

Comment: true, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62116652/one-hot-encoding-using-model-matrix

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77773716/6574038) how to get it working with multiple categorical variables.

Answer (score 22):

#### Code

```
library(data.table)
library(mltools)
customers_1h <- one_hot(as.data.table(customers))
```

#### Result

```
> customers_1h
id gender_female gender_male mood_happy mood_sad outcome
1: 10             0           1          1        0       1
2: 20             1           0          0        1       1
3: 30             1           0          1        0       0
4: 40             0           1          0        1       0
5: 50             1           0          1        0       0
```

#### Data

```
customers <- data.frame(
  id=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
  gender=c('male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female'),
  mood=c('happy', 'sad', 'happy', 'sad','happy'),
  outcome=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't want to use any external package I have my own function:

```
one_hot_encoding = function(df, columns="season"){
  # create a copy of the original data.frame for not modifying the original
  df = cbind(df)
  # convert the columns to vector in case it is a string
  columns = c(columns)
  # for each variable perform the One hot encoding
  for (column in columns){
    unique_values = sort(unique(df[column])[,column])
    non_reference_values  = unique_values[c(-1)] # the first element is going 
                                                 # to be the reference by default
    for (value in non_reference_values){
      # the new dummy column name
      new_col_name = paste0(column,'.',value)
      # create new dummy column for each value of the non_reference_values
      df[new_col_name] <- with(df, ifelse(df[,column] == value, 1, 0))
    }
    # delete the one hot encoded column
    df[column] = NULL

  }
  return(df)
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
df = one_hot_encoding(df, c("season"))
```

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 3):

Hi here is my version of the same, this function encodes all categorical variables which are **'factors'** , and removes one of the dummy variables to avoid **dummy variable trap** and returns a new Data frame with the encoding :-

```
onehotencoder <- function(df_orig) {
  df<-cbind(df_orig)
  df_clmtyp<-data.frame(clmtyp=sapply(df,class))
  df_col_typ<-data.frame(clmnm=colnames(df),clmtyp=df_clmtyp$clmtyp)
  for (rownm in 1:nrow(df_col_typ)) {
    if (df_col_typ[rownm,"clmtyp"]=="factor") {
      clmn_obj<-df[toString(df_col_typ[rownm,"clmnm"])] 
      dummy_matx<-data.frame(model.matrix( ~.-1, data = clmn_obj))
      dummy_matx<-dummy_matx[,c(1,3:ncol(dummy_matx))]
      df[toString(df_col_typ[rownm,"clmnm"])]<-NULL
      df<-cbind(df,dummy_matx)
      df[toString(df_col_typ[rownm,"clmnm"])]<-NULL
    }  }
  return(df)
}
```

Comment: since you remove one of the dummy variables, you should probably not call your function "onehotencoder". "one hot" means that one dummy is always "hot", i.e., 1 or TRUE.

Comment: The "dummy variable trap" I assume is perfect multicollinearity of the one-hot encoding. Dummy variable functions should automatically drop one variable as in dummyVars.