# Create time dummy variable for everytime period in the dataframe

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am trying to create time dummy variables for my dataset to conduct the analysis.
what i am trying to do is:
`df2$Q12012 <- ifelse(grepl("2012Q1", df2$datequarter), "1", "0")`,
`df2$Q22012 <- ifelse(grepl("2012Q2", df2$datequarter), "1", "0")`,
`df2$Q32012 <- ifelse(grepl("2012Q3", df2$datequarter), "1", "0")`,
`df2$Q42012 <- ifelse(grepl("2012Q4", df2$datequarter), "1", "0")`,
`df2$Q12013 <- ifelse(grepl("2012Q1", df2$datequarter), "1", "0")`........

I am trying to create the time dummy from 2012Q1 to 2021Q4, is there any function or package can help me finish this instead of typing code for every single time period? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62116652/one-hot-encoding-using-model-matrix

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
model.matrix(~datequarter + 0, df2)
```

Or you could do:

```
table(seq(nrow(df2)), df2$datequarter)
```

or

```
dummies::dummy(df2$datequarter)
```

NOTE:
This seems irrelevant if you are going to do modelling since the dummy variables will be generated on the fly.