# One hot fail - windows does not do one hot encoding

Tags: r

I'm new to R and can not get my head arround why [some very basic script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649443/how-to-one-hot-encode-several-categorical-variables-in-r) does **not** perform one hot encoding in a windows-environment while it performs totally well in a linux-environment. As I have to work within the failing windows-environment I'd like to make the script perform one hot encoding.

This happenes within windows (one hot fail)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252 LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.14.2 mltools_0.3.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.1  Matrix_1.3-4    tools_4.1.1     grid_4.1.1 lattice_0.20-44
>
> customers <- data.frame(
+     id=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
+     gender=c('male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female'),
+     mood=c('happy', 'sad', 'happy', 'sad','happy'),
+     outcome=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
>
> customers
  id gender  mood outcome
1 10   male happy       1
2 20 female   sad       1
3 30 female happy       0
4 40   male   sad       0
5 50 female happy       0
>
> library(data.table)
> library(mltools)
>
> customers_1h <- one_hot(as.data.table(customers))
>
> customers_1h
   id gender  mood outcome
1: 10   male happy       1
2: 20 female   sad       1
3: 30 female happy       0
4: 40   male   sad       0
5: 50 female happy       0
```

while this is what I'd expect to happen - one hot encoding

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Leap 15.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0   
> 
> customers <- data.frame(
+     id=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
+     gender=c('male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female'),
+     mood=c('happy', 'sad', 'happy', 'sad','happy'),
+     outcome=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
> 
> customers
  id gender  mood outcome
1 10   male happy       1
2 20 female   sad       1
3 30 female happy       0
4 40   male   sad       0
5 50 female happy       0
> 
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.14.2 using 8 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
> library(mltools)
> 
> customers_1h <- one_hot(as.data.table(customers))
> 
> customers_1h
   id gender_female gender_male mood_happy mood_sad outcome
1: 10             0           1          1        0       1
2: 20             1           0          0        1       1
3: 30             1           0          1        0       0
4: 40             0           1          0        1       0
5: 50             1           0          1        0       0
```

At least the same packages seem to be installed. So why does one hot encoding **not** take place without at least some error? Can anyone give me a hint how I get windows behaving?

Many thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: Does this behave differently if you are not using `data.table`? It seems a bit of a red herring here, I'd think.

Comment: Omitting ```# library(data.table)``` yields ```> customers_1h <- one_hot(as.data.table(customers))
Error in as.data.table(customers) :
  could not find function "as.data.table"``` - at least a decent error on the windows-side while Linux doesn't even notice.

Comment: Not using `library(data.table)` causes the missing `as.data.table()`. But removing this still causes the same behaviour.

Comment: If the problem has nothing to do with the `data.table` package (and specifically your use of `as.data.table`), then I suggest you reduce your code.

Comment: Thanks @MartinGal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this has to do with your R versions, not the platform. One of the key defaults for creating data.frames, `stringsAsFactors`, got a new default (`=FALSE)` in R 4.0 after years of tripping up unsuspecting new users. However, some packages, such as it seems `mltools`, expect the kind of data frame that would be created using the old default, `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. For more: https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/index.html

I was able to replicate the problem and could fix it by setting `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. (BTW, it looks like `mltools::onehot` expects a data.table as input, so I'm not sure there's a way to avoid using that package.)

Doesn't work:

```
customers <- data.frame(
id=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
gender=c('male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female'),
mood=c('happy', 'sad', 'happy', 'sad','happy'),
outcome=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0))

mltools::one_hot(data.table::as.data.table(customers))

   id gender  mood outcome
1: 10   male happy       1
2: 20 female   sad       1
3: 30 female happy       0
4: 40   male   sad       0
5: 50 female happy       0
```

Works:

```
customers <- data.frame(
id=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
gender=c('male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female'),
mood=c('happy', 'sad', 'happy', 'sad','happy'),
outcome=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

mltools::one_hot(data.table::as.data.table(customers))


   id gender_female gender_male mood_happy mood_sad outcome
1: 10             0           1          1        0       1
2: 20             1           0          0        1       1
3: 30             1           0          1        0       0
4: 40             0           1          0        1       0
5: 50             1           0          1        0       0
```

Comment: Great answer! Learnt a new source of problems today.