# CRAN R - Assign the value '1' to many dummy variables at once

Tags: r, dummy-variable, indicator, across, model.matrix

I have the following (sample) dput() for a dataframe consisting of non-unique IDs, countries, and columns representing country names:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4), country = c("USA", "Japan", 
"Germany", "Austria", "Japan", "Austria"), USA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), Germany = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Japan = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Austria = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Belgium = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

**I would like to alter the above dataframe** such that, for every id `i`, each column with a country name "I.e., `df$Germany`, `df$Japan`" has a value == 1 if `df$country` == 1. I.e., rows 1 and  2 should have `df$Japan == 1` and `df$USA == 1`; rows 5 and 6 should have `df$Japan == 1` and `df$Austria == 1`.

Are there any ways to do this without using for loops or pivot? (notice my current data has a "Belgium" column but no Belgium value in `df$country` -- pivot will not work here as far as I understand).

Someone on a different thread suggested: `df[levels(factor(df$country))] = model.matrix(~country - 1, df)` but this gives an **erroneous structure**, the dput being given below:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4), country = c("USA", "Japan", 
"Germany", "Austria", "Japan", "Austria"), USA = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), Germany = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Japan = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0), Austria = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), Belgium = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've also thought about using `mutate()` with `cur_column()` but I'm not sure as to how to even write that code.

Comment: That is my question, yes--none of those solutions solved my problem. I need to avoid for loops because of many observations (100k+ per dataset, and I have 30+ datasets) and pivot because the datasets don't list every country (i.e., in my above sample, there is no `df$country == 'Belgium'`

Comment: I have added a solution to your previous question here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904975/changing-values-of-many-columns-at-once-model-matrix/72913513#72913513>