# R functions to convert factors to numeric and then back to original factor levels

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a data frame containing a mixture of numeric and categorical variables (factors in R) such as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
                 age = c(18, 29, 55, 90, 44),
                 sex = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "F"),
                 category = c("cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2"))
```

I need to run some statistical analysis on this data but this analysis requires the input data to be in the form of a numeric matrix. I can of course convert `sex` and `category` into numeric variables by using something like `df$sex <- ifelse(df$sex == "M", 1, 0)` but this is very tedious to do manually when I have a lot of variables. Furthermore, the analysis will return a numeric matrix that I need to reconvert to the format of `df` with the original categories, and so I'll need to use something like `x$sex <- ifelse(x$sex == 1, "M", "F")` (here, `x` holds the return value of the analysis) to reconvert each variable back to the original data format, essentially undoing the first conversion. For simplicity please assume all the categorical variables are non-ordinal (i.e. there is no order to the categories) and binary (only two factor levels).

So I think what I want are 2 functions that can do this automatically. I'm assuming I'll need two functions `fct2num` and `num2originalfct`. `fct2num` will need to return the data frame as a matrix with my variables `fct_var <- c("sex", "category")` converted appropriately to numeric but also some sort of a dictionary `dict` of the mappings (e.g., `sex = "F" : 0, "M" : 1`) that I'll need to pass to `num2originalfct` along with the output of the analysis to be recoded back to the original categories. Any ideas or alternatives on how best to accomplish this? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649443/how-to-one-hot-encode-several-categorical-variables-in-r) would work for `fct2num` for one-hot encoding, but I'm not sure how I would revert the encoding back to the original factors.

Comment: Why convert to `0-1` instead of `1-2`? Also It is not clear as to whether to have different columns for each factor level. What if you had 3 levels? How will that look like?

Comment: @Onyambu Because the analysis requires me to parametrize categoricals with a binomial distribution so 0-1 is easier (ultimately it doesn't matter if the coding is 0-1 or 1-2). For 3 categories, it would be 0-3 coding instead of creating 2 one-hot vectors but as I mentioned, you can assume all factors have only 2 levels for this question.

Comment: Are you _certain_ you need to convert the data frame to a matrix for analysis? This seems like an unusual thing to have to do explicitly in R. What analysis are you trying to do? There may be a better way to tackle it. Sounds like this could be an xy problem.

Comment: @AllanCameron The analysis involves the copula package. I can feed it `df` without explicitly converting to matrix and it will run, but it will return a matrix with the categories coded as numeric, so I want to be able to convert that numeric matrix it returns to the original form.

Comment: Shall we assume you wanted the last category to be `cat2`? Data does not load as provided, since category only has four elements.

Comment: @JonSpring Yes my bad, I'll correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may strip off the factor labels using `as.integer` and subtract `1`.

```
> df[chr] <- lapply(df[chr], \(x) as.integer(as.factor(x)) - 1L)
> m <- as.matrix(df)
> m
     age sex category
[1,]  18   1        0
[2,]  29   0        0
[3,]  55   1        1
[4,]  90   1        1
[5,]  44   0        1
```

**Update**

To convert forth and back, you may follow an approach like this.

```
> df <- type.convert(df, as.is=FALSE)  ## convert character to factor
> fac <- names(df)[sapply(df, is.factor)]  ## store names of which are factors
> lev <- lapply(df[fac], attr, 'levels')  ## store levels of the factors
> df[fac] <- lapply(df[fac], \(x, y) as.integer(x) - 1)
> m <- as.matrix(df)
> m
     age sex category
[1,]  18   1        0
[2,]  29   0        0
[3,]  55   1        1
[4,]  90   1        1
[5,]  44   0        1
> ## do stuff with matrix
> df2 <- as.data.frame(m)  ## convert back to data.frame
> df2[fac] <- Map(`levels<-`, lapply(df2[fac] + 1L, factor), lev) ## restore levels
> df2
  age sex category
1  18   M     cat1
2  29   F     cat1
3  55   M     cat2
4  90   M     cat2
5  44   F     cat2
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(age = c(18, 29, 55, 90, 44), sex = c(1, 0, 1, 
1, 0), category = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How would I convert `m` back to `df` here?

Comment: Not sure, what do you mean by that exactly. Might help if you state, which kind of analysis you actually wanna do.

Comment: I mean what operation (other than `m <- df`) would I do so that I can get convert `m` to `df`. That's the biggest problem I'm having. I need to reconvert the `0-1` codings back to their original categorical levels (e.g., 'M' and 'F').

Comment: @elbord77 I understand, try update.

Comment: Amazing, I need to look into Map

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `1-2` coding:

```
data.matrix(df)

     age sex category
[1,]  18   2        1
[2,]  29   1        1
[3,]  55   2        2
[4,]  90   2        2
[5,]  44   1        2
```

If you need to transform to a `0-1` coding, then subtract 1 from the non-numeric columns:

```
t(t(data.matrix(df)) - !sapply(df, is.numeric))
     age sex category
[1,]  18   1        0
[2,]  29   0        0
[3,]  55   1        1
[4,]  90   1        1
[5,]  44   0        1
```

---

iF all the non-numeric have 2-levels, use `model.matrix:

```
model.matrix(~.,df1)[,-1]
  age sexM categorycat2
1  18    1            0
2  29    0            0
3  55    1            1
4  90    1            1
5  44    0            1
```

---

Update:

To toggle back and forth (using dataframes) you could use the following:

```
tonumeric <- function(x){
    isfactor <- !sapply(x, is.numeric)
    codes <- lapply(x[isfactor], \(x)levels(factor(x)))
    x[isfactor] <- data.matrix(x[isfactor]) - 1
    structure(x, codes = codes)
}

tocategory <- function(x){
    codes <- attr(x, 'codes')
    x[names(codes)] <- Map(\(i,j)j[i], x[names(codes)]+1, codes)
    x
}

d_numeric <- tonumeric(df)
d_numeric
  age sex category
1  18   1        0
2  29   0        0
3  55   1        1
4  90   1        1
5  44   0        1

tocategory(d_numeric)
  age sex category
1  18   M     cat1
2  29   F     cat1
3  55   M     cat2
4  90   M     cat2
5  44   F     cat2
```

Comment: Nice, but they want M=1 and F=0, suggesting `t(t(data.matrix(df)) - c(0, 1, 0))`.

Comment: @jay.sf the results have `M` as 1, I do not understand what you mean

Comment: @jay.sf also notice that in the comments, I asked whether OP cared about 1-2 coding or 0-1 coding, and they said they are fine with either

Comment: In `data.matrix(df)` alone we'd have M=2, F=1. Didn't read comments, OP should edit their question if they changed their mind.

Comment: @jay.sf they did not change their mind. I asked. Also I noticed that you commented while I was editing, probably thats why i got confused as to why you stated M=0F=1 yet I had that(after the edit). Its just that I read your comment, after I editted

Comment: So I guess we provided nice solutions.