# Beta-diversity analysis

Tags: r, cran, vegan

I'm new to understanding beta diversity and have been trying to follow this example given by R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hagis/vignettes/betadiversity.html

I want to replicate what was done similarly with beta dispersion in order to analyze variance between two groups: warm and cold years on species count data.
My meta data is set like this:
[image]

with species data being set as species matrix with the the individual species for each column and the years collected as the rows.
The tutorial mentions needing to set data into a binary code to run betadisper correctly, which I want to do(hot=1, cold=0 for example) but do not understand really how to set this up, given their example. Is anyone familiar with "create_binary_matrix" function or setting the argument to accomplish this task? I'm still fairly novice to R.

Comment: `data$Group <- ifelse(data$Group == 'hot', 1, 0)`

Comment: This would only change the Groups to binary code. I need the values of the species matrix to change to binary code it seems. So counts taken in warm years become 1 and those taken in cold years become 0. I'm assuming changing to binary is a necessary step following the tutorial, but Im not sure how much it makes a difference compared to simply using the regular counts. I have never done beta-dispersions before

Comment: It is very hard to help without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), other than us just repeating what is in the vignette you linked.

Comment: This sounds like [one-hot encoding, which has a FAQ here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48649443/903061). If you need more help than that, please make it easier to help you by providing both (a) sample input in a copy/pasteable format, `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` will create copy/pasteable code to recreate the first 10 rows of `your_data`. Choose a suitable subset to illustrate the problem. And also provide (b) your desired output for the sample input. This way we can test solutions and know if they are working.

Comment: Whatever tutorial you are reading is wrong (or you are misinterpreting it) and I should know as I wrote `betadisper()`. There is no need whatsoever to convert `Group` to be a dummy variable coded 0,1; a plain old factor will suffice.